# Пакет для склонения ФИО по падежам

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Всем привет, есть у кого пакет или функция для склонения ФИО по падежам в oracle

Comment: Фамилии иностранного происхождения не склоняются, русского - склоняются.  Как твой пакет поймёт что это за фамилия?

Comment: Так то можно какую-нибудь питоновкую `Natasha` припахать или другой `NLP` пакет, где есть склонения. Или это нужно прямо в `SQL` чисто сделать? Хотелось бы поподробнее задачу увидеть.